# Protractor test using phantomJS page css correct

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, phantomjs, protractor, functional-testing

We are writing functional tests for our new web app based on angular and using Material Design Lite as a front-end template.

I am running functional tests using phantomsJS as browser in order to orchestrate them using Jenkins later.

The problem i am facing is that the page styling is not correct, element are not in there place, some element are not showed or not styled. how can i correct that ?

Comment: Just FYI in case you didn't notice - the Protractor docs recommend you **do not use** phantomJS because there are several reported issues.

Comment: so if i want to run functional test in Jenkins or on each push to the repo how can i do this ?

Comment: Personally, I use VM's which run against a Selenium Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite arguable that you should run your end-to-end tests in PhantomJS - at least, because you are not going to get your real users using your application in PhantomJS. And, Protractor documentation itself [recommends against it](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#setting-up-phantomjs):

> We recommend against using PhantomJS for tests with Protractor. There
>   are many reported issues with PhantomJS crashing and behaving
>   differently from real browsers.

You can try upgrading PhantomJS to the latest (currently 2.1) version and see if it solves the broken layout problem.

Though, instead, look into using *remote selenium servers*, either your own, or provided by third-parties like [`BrowserStack`](https://www.browserstack.com) or [`SauceLabs`](https://saucelabs.com/).